# How to add Custom filed in Create Article layout of joomla?

Tags: php, joomla, article

I used Create Article Layout for add product in my website but now I want to add Custom Filed in this article layout to add price of product and this price must be save in content table of Joomla.

Give some suggestion how could I do this.

Comment: Why you are using article layout for managing products ? there are many cart extensions available in Joomla like Virtuemart,Hikashop,Joomshop etc

Comment: i used joomshop bt how to add product from front-end
vendor front-end is paid how i get free

Answer (score 0):

There is an official joomla tutorial about [Adding custom fields to the article component](http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_the_article_component).

You could download an **installation zip** at [Extension Files](http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_the_article_component#Extension_Files_2) section.

Hope this helps